# PTIJ: "until Elijah comes"?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

So I found a hand-made yarmulke the other day in my local synagogue. I tried to ascertain whose it was, but no one claimed it, and the rabbi told me יהא מונח עד שיבוא אליהו, I should hang on to it until Elijah comes.

Do I have to wait for the Pesach seder, or can I bring it to any bris? And then what do I do with it? Put it in his cup? Leave it on his chair? Or what?

Sourced answers preferred.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Related: https://judaism.codidact.com/posts/281230

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rabbi probably meant that you should keep it in a drawer until the [prophet Eliyahu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5_qxhBBCE0) returns to herald the coming of the [days of Mashiach](http://www.jewfaq.org/mashiach.htm), as predicted in [Malachi 3:23](http://www.sefaria.org/Malachi.3?lang=he-en&layout=block&sidebarLang=all):

> הִנֵּ֤ה אָֽנֹכִי֙ שֹׁלֵ֣חַ לָכֶ֔ם אֵ֖ת אֵלִיָּ֣ה הַנָּבִ֑יא לִפְנֵ֗י בּ֚וֹא י֣וֹם יְהוָ֔ה הַגָּד֖וֹל וְהַנּוֹרָֽא׃
>
> Behold, I will send you Elijah the prophet Before the coming Of the great and terrible day of the LORD.

I know that sounds a little outlandish, but your rabbi probably noticed  the writing along the bottom rim of the yarmulke:

[image: Yarmulke with the words "Yechi adnoneinu moreinu verabeinu, melech hamashiach, le'olam va'ed"]
<sup>Picture from [T.O.T.](http://privateinvesigations.blogspot.com/2013/06/chabad-yechi-yarmulke-at-center-of.html)</sup>

> יחי אדוננו מורנו ורבינו מלך המשיח לעולם ועד
>
> May our master, teacher, and rabbi, the annointed king live for ever and ever.

Clearly, it is inappropriate to display such words in the absence of a [properly-anointed](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0002_0_01124.html) king, which we're not expecting to have until after Eliyahu comes and announces it. Otherwise, one might be contributing to a false Messianism, which Judaism has seen [too many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Messiah_claimants) of already. So, your rabbi was wise to suggest that you put the yarmulke away until the right time.

I learned from one of my teachers in high school that this concept is also hinted to in the Hebrew name of this garment:

> Do you know why it's called a *kippah*? Because you're supposed to *keep* it in a drawer.

Answer (score 1):

Noticing the black and gold pattern on the Yarmulke, the Rabbi ascertained that it most probably belonged to someone from Munich, where [the official city colors are black and gold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munich).  Therefore he told you יהא מונח, it should remain in Munich, until Eliyahu can come and tell you which of its denizens misplaced it in your Shul.

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on whether Eliyahu Hanavi actually comes to the seder or to a bris. in regards to the seder, there is no classical jewish source that says that eliyahu hanavi comes to the pesach seder. Obviously we know that Eliyahu Hanavi will comes to herald the messaih and obviously  on the seder night where the focus is on redemption we hope that he will come to herald the redemption, thus the minhag evolved that we say he comes on the seder night. Indeed,  in reference to the fifth cup "kos shel eliyahu", the Mishnah Berurah (480:10) says that the cup is called Kos shel Eliyahu to allude to the fact “that we believe that just as God redeemed us from Egypt, He will again redeem us and send Eliyahu to announce it.” the earliest source for this 5th cup is in the writings of Rabbi Zelikman Binga, the son-in-law of the Maharil. In his commentary to Pesachim (sec. 11 page. 195), he reports seeing individuals pour a cup of wine at the Seder and refer to it as Eliyahu’s Cup. He proposed that the practice is probably related to our hope that Eliyahu will come on Pesach night, which as mentioned above is the night of redemption—to herald the arrival of Mashiach. Therefore, i wouldnt put the lost item in the cup, probably because the wine will destroy it. However, in line with our deep desire for redemption i would have the lost item on hand in order to give it to eliyahu when he comes, but if chas ve shalom in the event he did not come, i would keep watch of it till the heralding of the Moshiach.

In terms of his presence at brisos. The source for eliyahu coming is from the is Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer, (chapter 29) and Chazal instituted the Kisei Shel Eliyahu as mentioned in the Tur (YD 265), the Shulchan Aruch (YD 265:11), and the Aruch HaShulchan (YD 265:34). The Pirkei deRabbi Eliezer, doesn't actually say that Eliyahu will be present at each and every bris. All it says is that he will see with his own eyes that jews are performing the bris. As it says חייך שאין ישראל עושין ברית מילה עד שאתה רואה בעיניך. Rather the first place that says that Eliyahu will be at every bris is the Zohar: א"ל הקב"ה: חייך, בכל אתר דהאי רשימא קדישא די ירשמון ליה בני בבשרהון, אנת תזדמן תמן ופומא דאסהיד דישראל עזבו, הוא יסהיד דישראל מקיימין האי קיימא. I would suggest that its not a given if Eliyahu will be by any of these moments, so best bet is to wait till Mashiach.